Golang one-legged Oauth1
I am trying to generate a token so I can make one-legged Oauth 1 API calls, but I am having difficulty to understand how to do it in Golang.
I cannot find a package either. Hope someone can help me out.
I tried to get it working in Postman, this is working fine.
req.Header.Add("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"xxxx\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1712582585\",oauth_nonce=\"xxxx\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"xxxx\"")
But now I need to translate it to Golang. The data that I have is an authentication_key and an authentication_secret.
That's all I need to make the API calls.
Hope someone can help me out on how to create requests with a proper sign.
I tried to find packages, but none support one-legged OAuth 1 calls as far as I can see.
EDIT:
In Postman in the Authorization tab, I choose "Oauth 1". In the requet headers, all I fill in is the Consumer Key and the Consumer Secret. That's all!
I just cannot figure out how to transform everything to a signed version. This is what Postman creates:
$request->setHeader(array(
  'Authorization' => 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxx",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1712730107",oauth_nonce="TvB9wvmwPL0",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="tqyvNHstpQw4Zk%2Ba8r5PXIEetqk%3D"'
));


2-legged and 3-legged refer to the number of parties in the authentication flow. In the case of 2-legged that's just a client and a server. 1-legged makes 0 sense.

It look likes you are asking how to to sign a request given the consumer key, consumer secret, access token and access secret.  All oauth1 packages have this feature.

Nope, all I have is 1 key and 1 secret. That's all I have, and all I used in Postman too, and it is working perfect in Postman. This is how “they” designed their system.

Are the key and secret the consumer key and consumer secret?  What does Postman's Authorization header look like?

In Postman in the Authorization tab, I choose "Oauth 1". In the request headers field, all I fill in is the Consumer Key and the Consumer Secret. That's it for this API. The part where I am stuck is on how to transform everything to a signed version. I also updated my question.

The spec says that every request needs to be signed:

All Token requests and Protected Resources requests MUST be signed by the Consumer and verified by the Service Provider.

https://oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process
If there aren't any existing packages that do it, you'd have to follow the spec docs and write your own.
Code for generating the hmac sha1 signature in Go can be found in this question: Go Hmac SHA1 generates hash different from Hmac SHA1 in Java
The tricky part is assembling the correct "input" for it, because you have to put your request parameters in the right order and encode them correctly first. All of that is laid out in the spec docs.

Edit: I remembered I have a Spring application that accepts an OAuth 1.0 POST request and attempts to validate the oauth_signature. I was able to get it to successfully validate the request I created with this Go code:
package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    consumerKey := "yourkeyhere"
    consumerSecret := "yoursecrethere"

    uri := "https://youruri.com/api"

    now := time.Now().Unix()

    nowStr := strconv.FormatInt(int64(now), 10)

    // spec says nonce is supposed to be unique per request
    nonce := "aAbBcCDd98765axb9"

    form := url.Values{}
    form.Set("oauth_consumer_key", consumerKey)
    form.Set("oauth_nonce", nonce)
    form.Set("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1")
    form.Set("oauth_timestamp", nowStr)
    form.Set("oauth_version", "1.0")

    // The first part of my baseString is POST because I'm doing a POST
    // If yours is a GET, then you'd replace it with GET
    baseString := fmt.Sprintf("POST&%s&%s", url.QueryEscape(uri), url.QueryEscape(form.Encode()))

    // spec says the key for the signature should be secret + "&" + token,
    // but if you don't have a token then it's just secret + "&"
    sig := getSignature(baseString, consumerSecret+"&")
    form.Set("oauth_signature", sig)

    // if you're doing a GET request, then you wouldn't use the PostForm method
    resp, err := http.PostForm(uri, form)
    check(err)

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, _ := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    log.Printf("%d\n%s", resp.StatusCode, body)
}


func getSignature(input, key string) string {
    key_for_sign := []byte(key)
    h := hmac.New(sha1.New, key_for_sign)
    h.Write([]byte(input))
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
}

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

I also used this as a guide, though I think it's for PHP: https://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Signing.html

Thank you so much for this! I will give this a go tomorrow. This is awesome!
